# Batch Processing Image Files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, batch-processing, roi

I'm a beginner in MATLAB and image processing.

I encountered a problem while trying to use the batch processing and hope someone would be able to enlighten me. Thanks.

Following the example from MATLAB, I did these:

```
p = which('Picture1.tif');
filelist = dir([fileparts(p) filesep 'Picture*.tif']);
fileNames = {filelist.name}'

I = imread(fileNames{1});
imshow(I)
```

Because I wanted to select the region of interest,

```
BW = roipoly(I);
BW1 = not(BW);
N = roifill(I,BW1);
```

After I selected the ROI, I created a function in the editor:

```
function Segout = DetectLines(N)
    [junk threshold] = edge(N, 'sobel');
    fudgeFactor = .5;
    BWs = edge(N, 'sobel', threshold*fudgeFactor);
    se90 = strel('line', 3, 90);
    se0 = strel('line', 3, 0);
    BWsdil = imdilate(BWs, [se90 se0]);
    BWdfill = imfill(BWsdil, 'holes');
    BWnobord = imclearborder(BWdfill, 4);
    seD = strel('diamond', 1);
    BWfinal = imerode(BWnobord, seD);
    BWfinal = imerode(BWfinal, seD);
    BWoutline = bwperim(BWfinal);
    Segout = N;
    Segout(BWoutline) = 255;
end
```

Back to the command window, I typed;

```
Segout = DetectLines(N);
figure, imshow(Segout)
```

The figure that came out was what I expected.

The problem comes now when I try to loop over images. I'm not sure if I've done it 
correctly.

Following the example, I created another function in the editor;

```
function SegoutSequence = BatchProcessFiles(fileNames, fcn)
    N = imread(fileNames{1});
    [mrows, ncols] = size(N);
    nImages = length(fileNames);
    SegoutSequence = zeros(mrows, ncols, nImages, class(N));
    parfor (k = 1:nImages)
        N = imread(fileNames{k});
        SegoutSequence(:,:,k) = fcn(N);
    end
end
```

At the command window, I typed:

```
SegoutSequence = BatchProcessFiles(fileNames, @DetectLines);
implay(SegoutSequence)
```

However, the result was not what I wanted it to be. It was not the ROI that I wanted. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

#### Picture1:

[image]

#### Picture1 after selecting ROI:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Lookin at your code, you only selected the ROI once for the image you tested individually.

However, when you call the *BatchProcessFiles* function, you dont select a region of interest, and the *DetectLines* function is applied to the raw images... Therefore you need to pass the mask you created with *roipoly* to your *BatchProcessFiles* function to do the same on all the images.

As a side note, you might get better results if you try **Hough transformation** to detect the lines.
Also your code breaks if the images are not grayscale (you can add a call to *rgb2gray()* to be on the safe side)

Sample solution:

#### MATLAB

```
I = imread(fileNames{1});
BW = not( roipoly(I) );

SegoutSequence = BatchProcessFiles(fileNames, BW, @DetectLines);
implay(SegoutSequence)
```

#### BatchProcessFiles.m

```
function SegoutSequence = BatchProcessFiles(fileNames, Mask, fcn)
    % ...
    parfor (k = 1:nImages)
        N = imread(fileNames{k});
        if ndims(N)==3, N=rgb2gray(N); end
        if ~isempty(Mask), N = roifill(N, Mask); end
        SegoutSequence(:,:,k) = fcn(N);
    end
end
```

or call it as: `BatchProcessFiles(fileNames, [], @DetectLines)` if you don't need to apply the mask

Comment: +1: Should solve the problem, and I also believe a hough transform would be a better approach to solve the problem.